# Exchange 2003: how to enable RPC/HTTPS in a custom OWA website?

Tags: iis, exchange, exchange-2003, rpc

I have an Exchange 2003 SP2 FE/BE topology where the company is hosting two separate SMTP domains for two different sub-companies, so I created an additional OWA website as per [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995753(EXCHG.65).aspx).

Everything works fine: users in the first company access OWA via http://webservice.company1.com and users in the second one go through http://webservice.company2.com.

Now the customer is requesting RPC/HTTPS access for users in the second company, but using the address http://webservice.company2.com. It doesn't work, because the additional Exchange HTTP Virtual Server in the front-end server doesn't have the required /Rpc virtual directory; howewer, I'm unable to add it: the whole website seems to be managed by Exchange, and if I manually create virtual directories in it via the IIS manager they just don't work (404 error).

Is there any way to implement RPC/HTTPS in an additional web site which is running an Exchange HTTP Virtual Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened a support call with Microsoft and finally got it solved.

The problem is related to Exchange ISAPI filers, which (as I was supposing) intercept all calls to the HTTP Virtual Server and refuse them if asked for some URL that's not managed by Exchange.

Solution: remove the default application mapping to exprox.dll from the non-Exchange virtual directories when you create them via IIS manager. It works for standard virtual directories, and for RPC/HTTPS ones, too.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve the same problem.
If you export the configuration from the first Virtual Server (in IIS) and you create the new Virtual Server (setting the correct IP), it works (OWA, RPC over HTTPS)
The problem is that in this way the Virtual Server is not avaible in the System Manager.

Do you've find an other solution?

Fabio
superfabius@yahoo.it

Comment: You should **NOT** create OWA web sites from IIS; they really **need** to be managed by Exchange. Why didn't you create it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Li abbiamo creati da IIS perchè se li creiamo dal System Manager non funziona l'rpc/https.
Quello che non riusciamo a capire è da dove deve essere tolta la exprox.dll (se dalla root del sito o dalle subdir) quando crei il secondo sito dal sys manager.

Comment: Non credo sia opportuno parlare in lingue diverse dall'inglese qui dentro :-) Comunque, io ho semplicemente creato il sito da Exchange (con tutte le virtual directory del caso); poi ho creato a mano le vdir di RPC e **da queste** ho tolto i mapping a exprox.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Ok
We cannot find the exprox.dll on the RPC VDir (and also RPC with Cert) as you suggest. The exprox.dll is only in the VDir created automatically by System Manager on IIS when we made the second website (ExWeb, Public and so on..)

As I understand, do you find the exprox.dll when you create the RPC VDir on IIS?

Comment: You can find it as a jolly application mapping, visible by clicking the "Configuration" button in the virtual directory's application settings; the button is disabled is the vdir isn't part of an application pool, but the settings **STILL** applies, even if you can't see it; you can get to it if you create an application for the vdir (you can remove it after, if not needed).